# Pull data from phone that causes BSODS?

Tags: data-recovery, 7.1-nougat

*Bet you had to read that title twice.*

So the title says it all really - I have a Wiley-fox, a poor little thing that has been beaten up within an inch of its life. It **cant connect to my Wifi**, no idea why, it also **fails to recognize SIM cards**, but it seems the pins for that are damaged, and I need my old photos. Of course, if you read the title (if you think about it title is an odd word) I've tried **plugging it in only to get a BSOD.**

While I question why this phone has come from the seven circles of hell, does anyone have any ideas on how i can take my photos and stick them somewhere that doesn't spontaneously combust?

Comment: Try on a Linux system?

Comment: I would but I don't have a Linux system around atm.

Comment: How about simply copy pasting the files rather than doing a pull? Worst case scenario- send files via bluetooth.

Comment: Didn't think about Bluetooth, I'll admit. I'll try that